# How to get a whole word(not whole value) on jquery keypress event?

Tags: jquery, mysql, capitalization, reserved-words

I am working on a project where I want to capitalize each word, as you type in textarea on keypress event. Now, I am starting with just few words such as `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE`, which is by-default known as [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

I have created an array where I store this words. But now the problem I am facing here is how to get the whole word as you type the letters.

I have got few help from fellow stackoverflow threads, but I am unable to get any kind of help to get the value of whole word as you type the letters.

Example:
Original string will be like this 
`select name from accounts where id = '123'`

and as you type above string, the result should be like this
`SELECT name FROM accounts WHERE id = '123'`

Till now, I am able to capitalize the only one word in textarea, but I couldn't do it when I try to enter the whole sql. Below find the code, which I am using

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    var arr = ['SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE'];
    for (var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf($(this).val().toUpperCase()) == 0){
            $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Plenty of people like to write `select name from accounts`. I don't like that style so much, but you could annoy some people if this feature is forced on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string by spaces and map resultant array then join back with space

```js
var $input = $("#test").on('input',function () {
    var arr = ['SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE'];
    $(this).val(function(_, currVal){
        return currVal.split(' ').map(function(word){
            return arr.includes(word.toUpperCase())? word.toUpperCase() : word;
        }).join(' ')
    })
})

// set value and trigger event for demo
$input.val("select name from accounts where id = '123'").trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But this is not changing the case on keypress event of each letter.

Comment: It does once whole word is completed. Can't do it for single letters...could make this more complex and check when you get say 3 letters in a word grouping. Just have to make the mapping function do more parsing of the array. What is your expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression (that ignores case) to replace all the words within val(), like so:

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    var arr = ['SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE'];
    for (var i in arr) {
        // "i" ignores case and "g" makes the search global
        var regEx = new RegExp(arr[i], "ig");
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regEx, arr[i]));
    }
});
```

Comment: try using `.on` when using event and the for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object.use simple for loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But this is not changing the case on keypress event of each letter.

Comment: @TonyMontana you can change event to `input` and it will work on copy pasting in the textarea too

Comment: your solution has one flaw. What if the string contain 'anywhere'? it changes string to 'anyWHERE'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word bourdaries `\b` with regular expression and use the `input` even to detect the copy paste of string

```js
$("#test").on('input', function() {
  var arr = ['SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE'];
  let elem = $(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + arr[i] + ')\\b', "gi");
    elem.val(elem.val().replace(regex, arr[i]));
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```